# Subtract a constant value from elements in a non-scalar struct array in a vectorized way

Tags: performance, matlab, vectorization

I have a struct like this

```
temp_struct(1).budget=8
temp_struct(2).budget=8
```

and I want to subtract a constant value from both of them (replacing 8 with the new value). How can i do it more efficiently without using a loop in matlab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
%extract a cs list and convert it to a vector, then apply the operation you want in a vectorized manner
a=[temp_struct(:).budget]-42
%convert to cell because there is no direct way from vector to cs list
a=num2cell(a)
%use a cs list to assign the values.
[temp_struct(:).budget]=a{:}
```

[What is a cs list?](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html?s_tid=doc_12b&refresh=true)

Comment: deal is unnecessary, tested in matlab 2013a

Comment: Is this faster than a for loop? I get:  Elapsed time is 0.042050 seconds for this method and Elapsed time is 0.003850 seconds for for-loop

Comment: @JustCurious: In recent matlab versions, the speed of for-loops was increased, wouldn't surprise me if a loop is faster.